# Typescript validation issue when using Storybook with MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I have an Typescript validation issue when trying to pass args as children to a MUI button documented in Storybook :-(

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how I can pass this as children and not get a Typescript error? I assume it's unhappy as its not a ReactNode. TIA

Comment: Can you add the code for `Button` component please?

Comment: @GabrielPichot the code for the Button component is in MUI - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Mui Button doesn't have a label property.
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/
You need to extend the Mui Button Types. You can do something like:

```
import {
  ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps,
} from '@mui/material/Button';

interface ButtonPropsOverrides {
  label?: string
}

export type ButtonProps = MuiButtonProps & ButtonPropsOverrides;
```

Or do it like intended by Mui:

```
export default {
  title: 'Atoms',
  component: Button,
  args: {
    children: 'Label',
  },
} as ComponentMeta<Shape>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;
```

Because the Mui Button is using `children` as the actual label.